# Why my logs are not written to the file with config in properties file?

Tags: java, logging

I trying write log in file but file always empty and condole not display information. Why is problem?

```
private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class.getName());
public String book(){
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;
    try {
        fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("/home/user/Workspace/project/src/main/resources/logger.properties");
        properties.load(fileInputStream);
        LogManager.getLogManager().readConfiguration(fileInputStream);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    logger.info("INFO INFO");
    try {
        fileInputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**logger.properties**

```
# Logging
handlers = java.util.logging.FileHandler
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = ALL
# File Logging
java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern = /home/user/Workspace/project/super.txt
java.util.logging.FileHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
java.util.logging.FileHandler.level = INFO

# Console Logging
# java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = ALL
```

Comment: Please show the command you use to start, what version of Java you are using and what shows up on the console.

Comment: java 8, run application from ide, console don't show log msg

Answer (score 1):

Your config is not attaching a ConsoleHandler to any logger.

```
handlers = java.util.logging.FileHandler
```

Should be:

```
handlers = java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler, java.util.logging.FileHandler
```